# Setting environment variables for Google Cloud Text to Speech in Raspbian doesn't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-text-to-speech

I want to implement a text-to-speech function for my application using Python. However, I got this error after following a tutorial here https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tts.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/gapic/text_to_speech_client.py", line 84, in __init__
    scopes=self._DEFAULT_SCOPES,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 170, in create_channel
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

I've set the environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) using this command in Terminal and I am positive that my credentials are working as I've tested on other Google Cloud services.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/pi/labs/test/google_credentials.json"
```

Here are some of the things that I've done but didn't manage to work still

- Reinstalled google-cloud-texttospeech
- [Making credentials permanent](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/use-google-cloud-vision-on-the-raspberry-pi/)
- Ensure that my environment variables are set by using env & set | grep GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on the terminal to check
- Restarted my raspberry pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I managed to solve it by adding these two lines on my code:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/pi/labs/test/google_credentials.json"
```